# Sending files from Win8 PC to Ubuntu14.04 Laptop

Tags: wireless, files, transfer

I want to transfer some files from a PC with Windows 8 to my laptop with Ubuntu14.04 via WiFi Lan.But I don't know what to do. I already can connect to internet via the WiFi network of my modem-router but I don't know how to connect to the PC.Can anyone help?
I searched internet and this site for a similar question but found nothing.
Thanks

Comment: Is the process different from that of Windows 7?

Comment: I don't know! But there have been major changes from windows 7 to windows 8 so it may be!

Answer (score 1):

An easy cross-platform open source GUI tool for sharing files over your local LAN is [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net)

Simply install the program on the two computers in question and a representation of each machine will show up on the other's desktop. You can then drag and drop files onto the representation to send them to that machine. You'll have to accept the files on the recipient machine but it's possible to configure auto-accepting of files from machines you designate as trusted.

To install on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

Another option would be to install Dropbox or BTSync on both machines. These programs are cross-platform and allow you to share folders over your LAN or over the internet.

Comment: Thanks but that means uploading my files to internet and downloading them again. I'm talking about gigabytes of data, so that's not good for me.

Comment: With NitroShare, if both machines are on a LAN the files only go through your router or switch and won't use the internet. I believe BTSync also support local LAN sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scp protocol.
For windows there are a program named PSCP.
http://www.nber.org/pscp.html
Here's a example to use it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJbBpOptMjA

Answer (score 0):

I would use ftp. The client should be free for Windows (Filezilla) and the server is free for Ubuntu. Here is a guide on how to install an ftp server on Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html Hope that helps

Comment: This seems nice too. But i guess you meant setting up a FTP server on windows and a client on Ubuntu. I went for that but have problem configuring the FileZilla server on windows or maybe can't make the client working!!!...anyway, it doesn't work. I get "could not connect to server".

Comment: It seems the server is OK. I can access it via both ftp: //127.0.0.1 and ftp://<local IP> on the PC but on laptop, nothing comes out of typing ftp://<local IP> into Firefox's address bar and also from FileZilla client!

Comment: YES...YES...I did it. The problem was windows's firewall. I disabled it and now its OK. YES! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Mount your C: on your Ubuntu Server. That way, you don't have to revert any changes (ie uninstalling ftp server)

`smbclient <AdminPasswd> //<Win8MachineIP>/C$ -U <AdminUser>`

Comment: This seems nice, but I have a problem with it. I get the error:"tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. What should I do?

Comment: My bad... Try smbclient <AdminPassword> //<Win8MachineIP>/C$ -U <AdminUserName>. I've edited my original response for the purpose of archival and searching

Comment: Result: " <AdminPassword>: Not enough '\' characters in service". It seems this is not a standard format for the command!

Comment: lmao... subsititute your admin password for <adminPassword>, the IP of your Win8 Machine for <Win8MachineIP>, and your admin username for <AdminUserName>.

Comment: You really thought I wasn't doing that?!But...yes, you should have said that to be sure, so its OK.